# how to get function return response out of {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, promise

I'm trying to call a function in loop and function doing some https request the response is returning back to function and it returns **:**

`{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`

I want to return the exact value to that key where the function is called in the loop.

Here is my code **:**

```
 res.forEach(async (elem, index) => {
      await arr.push({
        id: index,
        name: '',
        color: '#2F14A8',
        chain: elem.chain,
        address: elem.walletAddress,
        balance: getWalletBalance(elem.walletAddress), //<---- **function call**

        img: images[index % images.length],
      });
    });
```

Here is the function **:**

```
const getWalletBalance =async address => {

let tokensArr=[] // some arry

    const res = await dispatch(getBalanc(address, tokensArr));
    return res;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the response for res in `getWallertBalance` function?
I think if u put await before `getWalletBalance(elem.walletAddress)` in forEach solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Those individual calls to `getWalletBalance` don't appear to depend on each other. The best way to do this is to produce a collection of promises with `map`, the resolve them concurrently...

```
const getWalletBalance = async address => {
  const res = await dispatch(getBalanc(address, tokensArr));
  const promises = res.map(element => getWalletBalance(elem.walletAddress));
  const balances = await Promise.all(promises);
  return res.map((element, index) => {
    return {
      id: index,
      name: '',
      color: '#2F14A8',
      chain: element.chain,
      address: element.walletAddress,
      balance: balances[i],
      img: images[index % images.length],
    };
  })
}
```